# How to achieve this shape using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I am trying to achieve the shape attached below using CSS. I have already figured out the similar shape but I cant think how do we show the borders in this shape.

Expected result is: [image: Ignore the text here]

What I have achieved until now is shown in below snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.rectangle {
    height: 99px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
}
.triangle-left{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 49.5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid white;
  border-bottom: 49.5px solid transparent;
}
.triangle-left-outline{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: -20px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 49.5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid black;
  border-bottom: 49.5px solid transparent;
}
.triangle-right{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 49.5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 49.5px solid transparent;
 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
    <div class="rectangle">
        <div class="triangle-left"></div>
        <div class="triangle-left-outline"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="triangle-right"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is impressive, but I wonder, is it worth polluting the HTML with non-semantic content just for an effect that can be achieved with just a background? Good luck anyway!

Comment: Perhaps an svg would help (which you can inline to cover @NikosParaskevopoulos point).

Comment: Yes I know this is not worth it and might be stupid as well but I am not familiar with svg's 
 and with advanced css as well, so any solutions that work will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Just embed svg file as the element background

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `clip-path` css property to achieve a shape like this...
Here is an example for the same

```css
.path {
  background-color: black;
  height: 30vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0rem 0.5rem;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 75% 0%, 94% 49%, 75% 100%, 0 100%, 13% 53%);
}

.path-container {
  background-color: orange;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 75% 0%, 94% 49%, 75% 100%, 0 100%, 13% 53%);
  padding: 0 1.6rem;
  height: 33vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 70vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="path-container">
      <div class="path"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**P.S. Expand snippet for better visibility**

For more info on how `clip-path` property works, refer to mdn [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea using skew transform:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.box:before,
.box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  border: 3px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box:before {
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transform: skew(20deg);
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  border-radius: 9px 9px 0 0;
}

.box:after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 9px 9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```